# Can you say: What o'clock is it?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I have read the following expression/sentence in "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland":

"And it (the watch) doesn't tell what o'clock it is".
(A Mad Tea-Party, chapter 7)

Source:
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland and Through the Looking-Glass, L. Carrol;  p. 68;  New American Library; 1960

Does it sound strange or even stupid today?

Comment: Not in modern English. :) That is the one of the best books every written.

Comment: @Lambie is right. Read it free at https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11

Comment: Correction: **That is one of the best books ever written**.

Answer (score 6):

Note, despite the 1960 copyright on your edition, *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* was written in 1865. Many usages in it are now outdated (and, be careful, many are unique to Lewis Carroll's eccentric linguistics). And yes, [this graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+o%27clock&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20o%27clock%3B%2Cc0) shows that "what o'clock" used to be much more common in past centuries (most of the modern usages seem to be works dealing with older literature, or math textbooks). I wouldn't say necessarily that it sounds *stupid*, or even outlandish, but your proposed replacements are more common in modern conversation.

Comment: Not 'stupid' or 'outlandish', but perhaps 'dated' or 'Victorian' are perhaps appropriate adjectives to describe that usage.

Comment: Same as any 18th century book. Nevertheless, I repeat: It is one of the best books ever written.

Comment: I don't know why your "this graph" link doesn't work for me (it just gives me "No valid ngrams to plot!"), but I tried editing your text to substitute a link to effectively the same chart that I'd already generated myself before reading your answer. But even ***my*** link produced that error message after I edited your text, so I've reverted it. There's something going on here that I don't understand (and I don't even know if it's connected to your answer or my browser! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know, I'm having the same experience! I wonder whether it has trouble parsing the apostrophe? But leaving it out of the search gives very different results. Well, suffice it to say that it shows higher use in the 19th century, a linear decline in the second half of the 19th century down to hardly anything, and a slight uptick in recent years (again, seemingly not new original uses).

Comment: I just tried again using the alternative way of including a link (link *after the end* of your actual Answer text), but it still doesn't work. I'm using the Brave browser under Linux Mint, but I'm guessing you're on something different, so it's probably *them*, not *us*. Maybe this is something worth raising as a "bug" on meta. And maybe the apostrophe is what's causing it, I dunno.

Comment: ...actually, I will just say that until I saw my usage NGram, I'd taken it for granted the cited usage was just Carroll's "facetious wordplay" (similar to today's *Oh dark hundred* for some ungodly hour in the morning! :) Note that *my* NGram compared ***What o'clock is it*** and ***What time is it***, and I must say I was truly surprised to see that 200 years ago, *both those two were equally common*.

Comment: Anyone who has read novels written before about 1900 will have come across 'what o'clock is it?'

Answer (score -3):

I'd say: Can you tell me what time it is, please? or

What's the time, please?

Comment: Well, "self-answering" is fine, and is in fact encouraged. I'm glad you're here, but I do encourage you to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on [what makes a good question and a good answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help). In particular, Stack Exchange isn't just a discussion forum, but focuses on concrete, factual answers, so we want to avoid quick or opinion-based ones.

Comment: @Andy, check the edit history. My downvotes for both the question and the answer were on the original versions and I don't see a reason to retract them.

Comment: @randomhead Sure, in fact I would have *flagged* the original version of both. I wonder whether some "test edits" got published... At any rate, Waldfee, in my opinion the current question is promising, and I hope you'll keep contributing and getting a feel for how it works.

Comment: @Lambie:, Andy and randomhead:  I am  still new here, although I have published several questions. I still have problems editing correctly. And sometimes I do not know where I am and where to click. Sorry for that. I do hope that I will improve.